# How to handle work flow for Master detail with stored procedure? Implementation advice needed

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, stored-procedures

I am at this point to save a class with Master detail. ASP.net webforms.  However, the requirement must be stored procedure and since it is using stored procedure, and ORM is not permitted.

This web app involves change of status as the form is sent to one person after another in a sequential manner, in addition allowing the user to void and save as draft for which the date and timestamp must be recorded as an audit trail.

I am thinking of using Json to save it to a big table.

Alternatively, I am thinking of saving it via 3 sections (which can be represented by 3 entities or value objects) in the form and then I use a single button update event to slot in the 3 updates.

Once, the table is inserted with data, I will use Json to bind to a data table and display with gridview.  User is able to click on the Form no and view it.  If the user is a Manager, then when the approval is done, use Json to update the table with status again.

Can someone tell me if the above implementation is feasible ?

Comment: You can call stored procedures from entity framework. To ascetrain this I searched in google for.... "call stored procedures from entity framework". You have a lot of statements and questions there. Perhaps you should first focus on the stored procedure implementation then worry about json and grids etc.

Comment: I am not allowed to use entity framework

Comment: entity framework is an ORM. So are you allowed to use any other ORM? If not then ORM is definitely not feasible regardless of whether you have stored procedures or not

Comment: I do not think so because the company prefers stored procedure way of doing things so logic is mostly contained inside Stored Procedure.

Comment: I have a web app whose logic is all in a stored procedure. I call that stored procedure through entity framework. Entity Framework doesn't stop you using logic inside stored procedures. Anyway..... it's clear you cannot use entity framework. So instead you just make direct calls without an ORM in the middle. Here is an example of a direct call to a stored procedure via ADO (i.e. not using an ORM) https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15403/Calling-Stored-procedures-in-ADO-NET

Comment: Hi Nick, I am able to do the Store Procedure or rather I have been using Store Procedure.  I am more concerned if my logic above regarding the flow is it correct or not because I want to use Json + jquery.

Comment: I can't see any specific question here. WIll json and jquery work to display data on a web form? yes.